# What data type is preferred for the parameters that have finite possible answer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, full-text-search, sqldatatypes

I use PostgreSQL on Rails, and was wondering what data type I should use to store  data efficiently.
For example, you can use a number from 0 to 2 to represent each gender, such as female, male, or other.
For countries whose number is finite, I would assign a number to each country like the example above because if I use string type, I am guessing that it would cost more space. Also, if a new country is made, you can easily add one more number to assign.

In these cases, what data type should I use?
Also, in these cases, how does full-text search work if a user looks up a name of a country, not the number that represents the country.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a Country model and make a relation between your records. By this way you can store only country ids on related records.

So the answer is integer.

Take a look here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html